# Create CloudFormation stack without resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using Terraform for most of my infrastructure, but at the same time I'm using the [serverless framework](http://serverless.com/) to define some Lambda functions. Serverless uses CloudFormation under the hood where I need access to some ARNs for resources created by Terraform.

My idea was to create a CloudFormation stack in Terraform and export all of the value that I need, but it complains that it cannot create a stack without any resources. I don't want to define any resources in CloudFormation, only the outputs, so I though maybe there is a way to define some dummy resource, but I couldn't find any.

Is there a way to work around this issue? If not, I'm also open to other suggestions for getting parameters passed from Terraform to CloudFormation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html) for this. Example:

```
Resources:
  NullResource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
```

Answer (score 10):

The Resource section is required, but you can create **non-resource** type of resource.

For example, minimalist template with only a **non-resource** would be:

```
Conditions:

  Never:
    !Equals [ "A", "B" ]

Resources:

  NonResource:
    Type: Custom::NonResource
    Condition: Never

Outputs:
  
  MyOutput:
    Value: some-value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use create AWS SSM parameter using Terraform and reference them in your serverless framework. That would do the job easily.

https://www.serverless.com/blog/definitive-guide-terraform-serverless/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).